# Dialogflow API how to send request using the api

Tags: javascript, google-api, google-cloud-platform, dialogflow-es

I have developed a small chat application using dialogflow fallowing this tutorial.

https://dialogflow.com/docs/getting-started/basic-fulfillment-conversation

this works fine. i want to send requests to this application from my alredy developed web application instead of using their web view (Web Demo). I thought it should be possible with their api (https://dialogflow.com/docs/reference/api-v2/rest). but their is no api exposed to send queries. am i missing something or is there no way to do this. ?

Comment: this libraray might help, https://www.npmjs.com/package/dialogflow-helper I wrote this library on the top of dialogflow rest client

Comment: I tried to make it as easy as possible, try it, let me know

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They changed the name fairly dramatically, and the names of many of the fields in the JSON, but the function is pretty much the same. You'll need to use the [`project.agent.sessions.detectIntent`](https://dialogflow.com/docs/reference/api-v2/rest/v2/projects.agent.sessions/detectIntent) method.

Answer (score 1):

You can find all the details about Dialogflow RESTful API [here](https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow-enterprise/docs/reference/rest/).

As Prisoner mentioned, you can use

```
POST /v2/{session=projects/*/agent/sessions/*}:detectIntent
```

For `v2.projects.agent.sessions`